# c++ (not >=11), initializing nested pairs in a map

Tags: c++, stdmap, c++03, std-pair

Under the restriction that I should not compile with -std=c++11, I want to add an additional variable to the following variable,

```
std::map<unsigned,
  std::map<unsigned,
    std::pair<
      std::pair<int, int>,
      std::pair<bool, bool>
    >
  >
>
temp;
```

and accordingly adjust its initialization:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
  {
    temp[i][i]=
      std::pair<
        std::pair<int, int>,
        std::pair<bool, bool>
        >
      > (
          std::pair<int, int> (intsX[i], intsY[i]),
          std::pair<bool, bool> (boolsX[i], boolsY[i])
        );
  }
```

I would like to change the structure to this:

```
std::map<unsigned,
  std::map<unsigned,
    std::pair<
      std::pair<int, int>,
      std::pair<
        std::pair<bool, bool>,
        double
      >
    >
  >
>
temp;
```

Now, I am not sure how to change the initialization, for example ...

```
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
  {
    temp[i][i]=
      std::pair<
        std::pair<int, int>,
        std::pair<
          std::pair<bool, bool>,
          double
        >
      > (
          std::pair<int, int> (intsX[i], intsY[i]),
          std::pair<std::pair, double> (
                                        std::pair<bool, bool> (boolsX[i], boolsY[i]),
                                        doublesX[i]
                                        )
        );
  }
```

I can use c++11 initialization lists as follows however is it possible to do this without using this c++11 feature(?):

```
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
  {
    temp[i][i]=
      std::pair<
        std::pair<int, int>,
        std::pair<
          std::pair<bool, bool>,
          double
        >
      > (
          std::pair<int, int> (intsX[i], intsY[i]),
          std::pair<std::pair<bool, bool>, double> ({boolsX[i], boolsY[i]}, doublesX[i])
        );
  }
```

Comment: Instead of hierarchical pairs and maps that emulate classes in your design, use classes - they are available without C++11....

Comment: @BartoszKP i should have made the context clear, apologies. This is in a program where I am unable to change thr layout but mees to add the additional double.

Comment: @James Maybe it is simpler to rewrite all the code in a normal way? Code like `pairVar.first.second.second.first` will confuse anyone.

Comment: @BartoszKP Indeed that code later on is confusing!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::make_pair` to make the code more legible.

```
temp[i][i] = std::make_pair(
    std::make_pair(intsX[i], intsY[i]),
    std::make_pair(
        std::make_pair(boolsX[i], boolsY[i]),
        doublesX[i])));
```

Comment: Great, this is nice, thanks. Out of curiosity is it possible to do it without using make_pair? So I can understand how the code will change.

Comment: @James Just change all instances of `std::make_pair` with `std::pair<type1, type2>`.